# Web template engine that checks property names during compile time

Tags: java, web, properties, template-engine

I'm looking for a web template engine (any language, Java prefered) that compiles template files before runtime. It should detect unknown property names and routes in my template. For example:

```
<h1>{{hello}}</h1>
```

should give a **compile error**, if there is no corresponding field on the model that I render.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you to take a look [Rythm template engine](http://rythmengine.org). Rythm is a static typed template engine for Java. You need to declare all the template parameters using `@args` directive. And the consequence is you get a type safe template with clear interface.

You can play with the online interactive fiddle site for Rythm at http://fiddle.rythmengine.org/

Disclaim: I am the author of Rythm template engine

**Updates to answer @user2043423's concern about attribute checking**

So first every rythm template is compiled into a java class, thus it's absolutely typesafe. second, because it is typesafe, it does check if the attributes exists in your Java class or not. For example you have a rythm template defined as:

```
@args Employee employee

Hello @employee.getFistName()
```

You will get a compilation error when you run the template because there is a typo in `@employee.getFistName()`, and once you fixed that to `@employee.getFirstName()` the rythm will go ahead to render the template

In case you want to check if the template argument employee has been passed to the template or not, use `@if`:

```
@args Employee employee

@ifNot(employee) {
    @return
}

Hello @employee.getFirstName()!
```

See http://rythmengine.org/doc/directive.md#if for more about `@if` directive

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Indeed Rythm goes in that direction, but I found no way to check whether or not my attribute exists or is set in the model. i.e. `@args String hello` should compile/parse to some Java class I can work with.

Comment: I've updated the answer to address your concern about attribute checking

Answer (score 5):

I've implemented [static-mustache library](https://github.com/sviperll/static-mustache) to provide a type-safe template engine based on mustache syntax, like the one in your question.

It checks both syntax errors and type-errors (like missing property) at compile-time. It requires zero build configuration as it's a standard annotation processor.

Templates remain pure mustache templates with all type-information extracted from normal Java-class used for rendering.